# Анимировать заполнение бутылки

Tags: java, android, анимация

Пишу приложение  [Aqua Balance](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.validcat.st.wb&ah=WK1XKkri7QOyZGYdcBkW2iIUK6o&hl=ru). Помогает контролировать объем выпиваемой воды. Необходимо анимировать наполнение бутылки при нажатии на кнопку выпить,отрисовать количество выпитой воды в процентном соотношении к размерам бутылки. Сейчас у меня там 10 картинок, и они меняют друг друга. Это меня устраивало, пока не добавил настройки в приложение(на данный момент можно пить только 2 литра, без выбора). После добавления настрое объем меняется, и не корректно использовать старые картинки.

Вопрос: подскажите каким способом лучше это реализовать, куда копать, что читать?

Я делал так, находил размер бутылки(`view.getHeight();` , `view.getWidth();`), и в процентном соотношении рисовал прямоугольник. Но это не совсем удачно, т.к. размер находился только после клика, и при первом открытии не отрисовует, а так же необходимо каждый раз удалять и рисовать заново, как бутылку так и воду, что приводит к затиранию подсказок на кнопках.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: а анимации вообще не было? просто замена получается слоев, выкрашенных в цвет воды? Кстати в приложении, остается тень при заполнении воды по скринам видно, не очень красиво.

Comment: Анимации небыло раньше

Answer (score 1):

Ну вроде можно svg добавлять в андроид. Нарисуй изначальную бутыль, а заполнение уже сделай по высоте. например, высота бутылки 500. Емкость 100 мл.
Отношение 5:1.
Вот и отрисовывай 1/5 от бутылки, если 20мл выпили.

Comment: Это прямой пример когда, не надо использовать векторную графику для такой простой анимации. Существует огромное кол-во способов, чтоб это сделать красиво, и не нагружать поток. Вы абсолютно ошибочно даете ответ.

Comment: Не подскажете парочку из них?)

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, я и не говорю, что он правильный. Я просто выражаю свое мнение. 
ИМХО, так сказать.